# Download close prices of S&P500 components

Tags: r

i'm quite new here and stuck  with quite peculiar problem here (as i think for myself). I have a column with all S&P500 tickers (MMM, ABT, ABBV, ACN, ATVI, AYI, ADBE....). Then, i perform some code, requesting xts for every ticker. I'm not good at creating loops, so i did in such a way (first column consists of tickers):

```
sp500=read.csv(text=getURL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/s-and-p-500-companies/master/data/constituents-financials.csv"),  header=T)
n=nrow(sp500)
for(i in 1:n) {
  j <- sp500[i,1]
  getSymbols(j)
  j=as.data.frame(j)      
}
```

So i get a lot of datasets, called the same way, as the tickers given in column, that was mentioned before . But the problem is in the fact, that i have, somehow, to make a sort of aggregated dataset, consisting of one exact column  from each dataset. In other words, i have to take `MMM$MMM.Close` and add `ABT$ABT.Close` and so on.

I suppose, that it would be long to do it manually, so i'd like to find out, how is it possible to address code to those datasets one-by-one (with loop), knowing it's names from the column with tickers?

Comment: not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code that downloads daily CLOSE prices for the selected tickers (credit to @Quant Guy). I couldn't open your file and can't find a free reliable source (apart from wikipedia to find all the S&P500 index components), so I manually entered the tickers:

```
library(quantmod)
    tickers = c( "WMT", "MMM","AIG", "AAPL", "KO",
             "COST", "C", "AMZN", "ICE", "VTR")

getSymbols(tickers, from = "2010-01-01", to = "2015-12-31")
P <- NULL
seltickers <- NULL

for(ticker in tickers) {     
  tmp = Cl(eval(parse(text = ticker))) ## Cl from quantmod
  if(is.null(P)){ timeP = time(tmp) }
  if(any(time(tmp)!=timeP)) next
  else P = cbind(P, as.numeric(tmp))
  seltickers = c(seltickers, ticker)
}

P = xts(P, order.by = timeP)
colnames(P) = seltickers
```

Just modify the `tickers` and you should be good to go.